# Invalid argument received while using HttpClient

Tags: c#, httpclient, .net-5

I am trying to get web api data in console application. Receiving data works correctly until I try to connect additional classes from **my other library called "Nsi"** to the application. As a result, receiving data fails with an Invalid argument received error. Changing the library name resolves the error. All libraries are built on the Net5 platform

Link to sample project
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1wftAzUWqtEefdv2vWiOwzuNGHBvmehG9?usp=sharing

Console application:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var httpServices = new ServiceCollection();

    httpServices.AddHttpClient<IHttpService, HttpService>();

    httpServices.AddTransient<ITest, Test>(); 

    var httpServiceProvider = httpServices.BuildServiceProvider();

    var client = httpServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IHttpService>();

    var ss = client.Get("https://www.google.com/");

    Console.Write(ss);
}
```

Plug-in classes:

```
public class HttpService : IHttpService
{
    private readonly HttpClient Client;
    public HttpService(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        Client = httpClient;
    }

    public string Get(string url)
    {
        return Client.GetStringAsync(url).Result;
    }
}

public interface IHttpService
{
    public string Get(string url);
}
```

This class has been placed in a separate library "Nsi":

```
public interface ITest
{
    void TestMethod();
}

public class Test : ITest
{
    public void TestMethod()
    {
    }
}
```

Error
["One or more errors occurred. (Invalid argument received. (www.google.com:443))"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thZcX.png)

Comment: Firstly, don't do this `return Client.GetStringAsync(url).Result` await it like you know you should. Secondly. there is not enough information here to help you.. My guess is you are looking at different classes.

Comment: Yes, I know not to do this, I wrote it in such a way to simplify the example - using async / await, the result does not change, an error occurs. What do you mean "different classes"? What other information is needed to find the error?

Comment: Do you mean the code in the "Main" block? It differs by one commented out line, if you uncomment it the code stops working. This line // httpServices.AddTransient<ITest, Test>();

Comment: Yeah this dosnt really make sense. I cant reproduce this

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/eJnP6v

Comment: Yes, the code works if placed in one project. But in my case, the **Test class was moved to another project (library)** and the code stops working

Comment: Just moved my classes and interfaces to another project (.net standard) and it worked

Comment: Yes, I created a completely new library and moved the Test classes there, the code worked. Then I really don't understand what's wrong with the existing library, I can't recreate it or use another one instead.

Comment: Its likely just a simple mistakes, something like your classes are not what they seem, or something else benign. At least you have a working example

Comment: Empirically found out that the application stops working if the second library has the name Nsi (case insensitive). Renaming the second project fixes the problem. Here is the [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1wftAzUWqtEefdv2vWiOwzuNGHBvmehG9?usp=sharing)